# Convert binary <something> of hex bytes to list of decimal values

Tags: python-3.x, binary, hex

I have the following binary (something):

```
test = b'40000000111E0C09'
```

Every two digits is a hexadecimal number I want out, so the following is clearer than the above:

```
test = b'40 00 00 00 11 1E 0C 09'

0x40 = 64 in decimal
0x00 = 0 in decimal
0x11 = 17 in decimal
0x1E = 30 in decimal
```

You get the idea.

How can I use `struct.unpack(fmt, binary)` to get the values out? I ask about `struct.unpack()` because it gets more complicated... I have a little-endian 4-byte integer in there... The last four bytes were:

```
b'11 1E 0C 09'
```

What is the above in decimal, assuming it's little-endian?

Thanks a lot! This is actually from a CAN bus, which I'm accessing as a serial port (frustrating stuff..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have string `b'40000000111E0C09'`, you can use `codecs.decode()` with hex parameter to decode it to bytes form:

```
import struct
from codecs import decode
test = b'40000000111E0C09'
test_decoded = decode(test, 'hex') # from hex string to bytes

for i in test_decoded:
    print('{:#04x} {}'.format(i, i))
```

Prints:

```
0x40 64
0x00 0
0x00 0
0x00 0
0x11 17
0x1e 30
0x0c 12
0x09 9
```

To get last four bytes as UINT32 (little-endian), you can do then ([`struct` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment))

```
print( struct.unpack('<I', test_decoded[-4:]) )
```

Prints:

```
(151789073,)
```

Comment: That's beautiful, exactly what I needed. Love it that you first edited my question to make it easier to read, and then answered it so expertly :)